# How to control a device that need to be updated over internet?

Tags: arduino, programming, wifi, home-automation

I know, the question is very vague, but I'll try to explain better.

I'm working in a school project and I got interested in continuing this project after school. **It's a automatic aquarium**. I want to control everything that happens in a aquarium, so I used an `Arduino Uno` connected to some sensors and some activators - *sorry, I don´t know the right terms*.

Everything works ok.

But... I got the idea to control this system remotely, connecting it to the internet through a wifi connection using an `wifi shield`. Ok, seems possible to do, but I also want to change all "program" remotely. I mean, the user, by a site or app, would be able to select a fish and the `Arduino` would change all the environment to better grow that specie. And I imagine it requires a "reprogramming" of `Arduino` and its seems impossible to be done by wifi connection.

So... The question is:

1. Can I achieve it using an Arduino? What version of Arduino? And How?
2. If its impossible to achieve it with an Arduino, how could I achieve it?

Comment: Why reprogram the arduino for each new fish? If you get an arduino with enough space you can write an 'if' statement for each fish and then send a command via wifi to run that section of code.

Comment: @Hayman I know, but I also think in use this approach to keep the Arduino updated with new features. I'm sure that I will want to change something in the software in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are high chances you don't need to reflash remotely. Just write a generic control algorithm supporting all target sensors and actuators, and let the user download configuration parameters which could be stored in [EEPROM](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROM). Then update those parameters remotely.

If you insist on remote reflashing, you should also design a bootloader which takes a hand if the last reflashing attempt was unsuccessful. Otherwise your system will be easy to "brick".

Comment: The `remote reflashing` is also for update the software with new features. Thanks for the answer, I will research about you bootloader approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

you should check out the ESP8266 boards, thay are cheap (around 3$ each) and has built-in wifi and can be programmed with the arduino IDE